# How to read the mta.yaml File [SAPUI5]

Tags: javascript, yaml, sapui5, ui5-tooling

For an Issue given, it is required to read the `mta.yaml` File programmatically.

**Attempt:**
Trying to read the file via `.fileReader` => doesn'work

**Question:** How to read mta.yaml programmatically ?

Comment: Can you provide context? Where do you want to read the file? During deployment? Or in the app?

Comment: `mta.yaml`, does contain the `version` of the app, this version should be displayed in the frontend, hence there is a need to read the file

Comment: mta.yaml is not part of the webapp folder usually. So during deployment you could automatically copy the file to your webapp folder so it will be included in the dist folder. Or you could create a json file in your webapp folder which will contain the version number.

Comment: if i were to take the `JSON` - File path, would it be required to manually update the file, if the `mta.yaml` file is changed ?

Comment: Yes. But you can script this in your deployment pipeline.